# Removing Alpha Channel in Node Editor

Tags: node-editor, transparency

five month old newbie who's having some fun, here. I've been experimenting a bit, and got a problem. I was following this tutorial
from Zacharias Reinhardt on how to create massive background forests via alpha channels.
Seems to me to be the best method there is, if you're aiming for not too much processing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtUS8QTsVZA

And then I got stuck in the node editor when removing the black alpha channel part of the png.
I'm 99% certain I did everything exactly like Zacharias showed in the tutorial,
but somehow, I'm getting a somewhat different result? And yes, RGBA was selected during export of the original file.

I've added a screenshot of the section in the tutorial and a screenshot
of what I've got on my screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kind of hard to know what is wrong without the .blend file. Maybe try changing the color of the Transparent BSDF with the Alpha channel turned to 0 instead of 1

Comment: Hey WhatAMesh,

my previous setup was from a saved template, so I redid everything from factory settings, only enabling the NodeWrangler and Image from Planes addon and got it to work. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Hey cegaton,

thanks a lot for the link.

I'd exported everything as RGBA, and instead of drag/drop, used the Import Images as Planes addon this time and made sure enable "Use Alpha".

This time it worked, but once I switched to Cycles Render it went completely white. So I started in Cycles and then it worked. And using Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C, I reset the origin/pivot point, so everything's working now again!

(Still learning my way around SEs posting stuff. Pardon that.)

Answer (score 0):

To help troubleshooting, add an emission node and set it as alpha channel viewer, because it looks like there is an uncorrect alpha channel.

An useful shortcut for this procedure is to enable the Node Wrangler Add-on and Shift Ctrl click on a node a couple of times to temporarily view its output values.

[image]

Also checking the image in a 2D app (Gimp, Photoshop) could help, because the Blender setup looks correct.

Comment: Hey Josh,

thanks. I added the emission and I'm seeing exactly what you're having. I got it to work with cegaton's help. Much appreciated! :)